# Showing txt file details

Tags: c++, qt, text

I have a `.txt` file with these contents:

```
good  
bad  
hi
```

I want the Next button to cycle through these words, but with my code I only get the word "good". When I click Next, it doesn't show the next word. Here is my code with `Qt 5.4`.

```
void MainWindow::on_Next_clicked()
{
    ui->ShowEn->clear();
    ifstream Sfile("E:\\en.txt");
    getData(Sfile);
    Sfile.close();
}

void MainWindow::getData(std::ifstream& myfile)
{

    if(!myfile.eof())
    {
        std::string str;
        getline(myfile, str);
        ui->ShowEn->setText(QString::fromStdString(str));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sfile needs to survive multiple `on_Next_clicked`.=> Put it into MainWindow scope etc.

Comment: make the wording a little clearer, minor grammar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time this method is executed:

```
void MainWindow::on_Next_clicked()
{
    ui->ShowEn->clear();
    ifstream Sfile("E:\\en.txt");
    getData(Sfile);
   Sfile.close();
}
```

The file is opened anew and the first bit is read with getData. The file is then closed. Every time the file is opened, reading starts over from the beginning, which is why you see the same string every time.

You probably want to open your file somewhere else (the window's constructor, perhaps?), then simply read it on each button click. This will require a member variable in `MainWindow` to hold the open file. Don't close it until you're done.